# Azure 1.7, Visual Studio and UAC prompts

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, uac

Running Visual Studio Ultimate 2010 on Win7 x64. I just installed the latest Azure SDK and upgraded a web role. When I enter the debugger from Visual Studio, I need to click through two UAC prompts before the site appears. I believe these are for the compute and storage emulators. How do I prevent this from happening? I already run Visual Studio as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

On my development machines I tend to disable UAC completely:

- Control Panel
- User Accounts
- User Accounts (again)
- Change User Account Control settings
- Drag the slider to the bottom: **Never notify**